# rgbdslam commands/steps to localize in preSaved map

Tags: slam, localization, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there. I am able to successfully record an map with rgbdslam but I am struggling to figure out the steps and commands that I need to run to load the map to the map servers and then how to then use that to localize the kinect in the previously saved map. Any help would be greatly appreciated and extra details on the actual commands to run for 1) loading saved map to mapserver, 2)localize in it, 3) display resultes in rviz or something similar" would benefit many users.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56976/rgbdslam-commands/steps-to-localize-in-presaved-map/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know the exact details about localizing with RGBD-SLAM. But you could load the stored OctoMap file in [octomap_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_server) and then localize with [humanoid_localization](http://www.ros.org/wiki/humanoid_localization). I haven't really tried it for a free-floating Kinect, only an ASUS Xtion mounted on a humanoid. So you may have to perform some adjustments in the code (humanoid_localization requires some sort of odometry!).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2013-03-04**:
What you outlined is exactly the details I am trying to see if anyone has. Basically, what is the command to load the map to the octomap_server and what are the commands in humanoid localization to then localize in it. Somebody must have tried this and gotten it work work.